# SDL_PixelFormatEnumToMasks() causing compilation issues

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I feel like I made a simple mistake that I cannot find, when ever I compile this code it takes me to a file named 'Makefile.win' and returning a bunch of compiler errors concerning the parameters of SDL_PixelFormatEnumToMasks().

code:

```
#include <SDL.h>
int main( int argc, char *args[] )
{
    Uint32 format = SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGB888;
    extern int bpp;
    extern Uint32 Rmask, Gmask, Bmask, Amask;
    SDL_PixelFormatEnumToMasks(format, &bpp, &Rmask, &Gmask, &Bmask, &Amask);
}
```

errors:

> main.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr.bpp[.refptr.bpp]+0x0): undefined reference to
>   'bpp'
>   main.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr.Rmask[.refptr.Rmask]+0x0): undefined
>   reference to 'Rmask'
>   main.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr.Gmask[.refptr.Gmask]+0x0): undefined
>   reference to 'Gmask'
>   main.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr.Bmask[.refptr.Bmask]+0x0): undefined
>   reference to 'Bmask'
>   main.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr.Amask[.refptr.Amask]+0x0): undefined
>   reference to 'Amask' [Error] ld returned 1 exit status recipe for
>   target 'Project3.exe' failed

Comment: Don't declare the variables as `extern`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared your variable as `extern`. For the compiler, it means those variables are defined in another scope of another file, and try to find it in any library/file that you linked with your `main.cpp`.

If you just want to use your variables like `format`, don't declare it as `extern`.